# automated test for SSRS reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, ssrs-2012

I have 187 reports in a live SSRS/SSAS scenerio.  I have a requirement to update the cube all of the reports are feeding from.  The requirement is spawned from a change request to one of the reports.

Is there a quick way to determine whether or not I have broken all the other reports based on the new cube design (in short terms, how do I perform automated regression testing?)

Thanks much!

Comment: If you just changed underlying business logic and didn't change any column names, everything should still work. If you really want, you could get all the MDX queries from the report server and try running those to see if they still work. All SSRS cares about is that the queries run and the column names haven't changed.

Answer (score 1):

Best thing I can think of is to set up a subscription for every report that goes to an empty folder on a file share, or email if you prefer. If there is less than 187 reports in the folder, then you have a broken report.

You can then create a query of the SSRS database subscriptions table to find the subscription that errored, and which report it was, to go test it further.

If you want to automate the creation of the subscriptions for the reports as well, you could use something like this tool. https://www.2ndrock.com/software/subscriptionmanager/subsmgr.html